# Failed OpenVPN Connection to Server

Tags: vpn, openvpn, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to set up my own VPN using a Raspberry Pi but get the following error during startup: `Failed OpenVPN Connection to Server`

I'm using the latest Raspbian and following this tutorial: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-33548728

My static IP is 192.168.1.8 and my router's is 192.168.1.1. I'm trying to do this using wlan0.

My `/etc/openvpn/server.conf` file reads:

```
local 192,168.1.8 #RASP PI Static Ip Address
dev tun
proto udp
port 1194
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/#MYSERVER#.crt #Server name
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/#MYSERVER#.key #Server Name
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh1024.pem #If you chose 2048 change it here
server 10.8.00 255.255.255.0
#server and remote endpoints
```

`ifconfig -a` shows:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:f9:61:05
          inet6 addr: fe80::f933:3ab8:d352:8bad/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:204 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:204 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:16896 (16.5 KiB)  TX bytes:16896 (16.5 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:ac:34:50
          inet addr:192.168.1.8  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:feac:3450/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:544 errors:0 dropped:191 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:295 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:116710 (113.9 KiB)  TX bytes:44995 (43.9 KiB)
```

`ps aux | grep openvpn` shows:

```
root      1069  0.0  0.2   4276  2004 pts/0    S+   21:58   0:00 grep openvpn
```

nano /etc/network/interfaces reads:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static

address [192.168.1.8]

netmask [255.255.255.0]

network [192.168.1.0]

broadcast [192.168.1.255]

gateway [192.168.1.1]

#       pre-up /etc/firewall-openvpn-rules.sh

    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

I'm not sure how to display the contents of `/var/log/openvpn` at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line appears to be wrong, you've got a comma instead of a . in the IP.

```
local 192,168.1.8 #RASP PI Static Ip Address
```

Should likely be

```
local 192.168.1.8 #RASP PI Static Ip Address
```

Also, for monitoring a log file try using tail (in a shell prompt):

```
tail -f /var/log/openvpn
```

and use <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> to exit it.

Comment: I've corrected the mistake and rebooted, but still get the same error. I've tried the tail command but it says there is no such file or directory.

Comment: nano /etc/network/interfaces reads:  # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)  
  
# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd  
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'  
  
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:  
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d  
  
auto lo  
iface lo inet loopback  
  
iface eth0 inet manual  
  
allow-hotplug wlan0  
iface wlan0 inet static    
  
address [192.168.1.8]  <br/>
  
netmask [255.255.255.0]

Comment: I dont understand how to format these comments see original post.. i've added my nano /etc/network/interfaces which i think is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I solved this by removing the line:

```
 local 192,168.1.8 #RASP PI Static Ip Address
```

from my `/etc/openvpn/server.conf`file